# Add event handler to HTML Progress tag

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

I´m trying to assign an event handler for a HTML  tag, I want to fire a function when the value changes, but none events are fired..

```
<progress
   id="side-cart__progress-bar" 
   class="side-cart__progress-bar"
   first-gift="{{ section.settings.product_1_progress_bar.id }}"
   first-goal="{{ first_goal }}"
   second-gift="{{ section.settings.product_2_progress_bar.id }}"
   second-goal="{{ second_goal }}"
   final-gift="{{  section.settings.product_3_progress_bar.id}}" 
   max="{{ final_goal }}" 
   value="{{ cart.total_price }}"
  >
</progress>
```

Here's my JS:

```
const $sideCartProgressBar = document.querySelector("#side-cart__progress-bar")

$sideCartProgressBar.addEventListener("change", function(){
   console.log('Hello')
})
```

Comment: Please update your code such that it meets the standards of being an [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<progress>` does not support a `change` event listener. In addition, as far as I know, it raises no event when you change its `value`.

You can see, for example, [MDN documents the existence of the `change` event on `<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#events) but there is no similar documentation of `change` event on `<progress>`, supporting my claim that [there is no such event for `<progress>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLProgressElement#events). In fact, there are no documented events for `<progress>` at all (besides inherited DOM events).

You should find some other way to do this, such as modifying the code which updates cart.total_price to do something extra when final_goal is reached.